# Database Diagram Designer - Howto jump to a specific table?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, database-diagram

i am using Microsoft SQL server Management Studio 2012 to create a database diagram for my whole database (more than 200 tables).

Is it possible to find / jump to a specific table in diagram?

I need a tip.

Thanks.

Comment: If you show the Properties window (View->Properties Window) you can see a drop-down list of objects, which I find quite useful for jumping around (click on the background of the diagram to scope the list to "everything".) Is that the kind of thing you're looking for?

Comment: Yes. Great. Thanks. That's what i am looking for.

Comment: Cool. I shall post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Properties Window is useful for this. It has a drop-down list of objects in the currently-selected scope, in type/alphabetical order. (To see a list of everything, I usually click on the background of the diagram to make sure the whole diagram is selected.)

To [show the window, choose View→Properties Window](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189072(v=sql.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Screenshot 1]

First Select your data table and Click there I point with blue cycle.